# Reference needed for this result of orthogonality in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $H$ be an Hilbert space and let $V$ an its finite dimensional subspace. Let $J:v\in V\mapsto J(v)$ be a coercive, bounded from below and weakly lowersemicontinuous functional.

On my notes, it is written that $v^{\prime}\in V$ exist such that
$$J(v^{\prime}) =\inf_{v\in V} J(v).$$
I guess it is a well known result of functional analysis (possibly it is something known as theorem of existence of a minimizer, or nearly).

The other thing written on my notes and that I am trying to understand is the following:

"moreover it is $J^{\prime}(v)\perp V."$

Honestly, I don't know where'd that come from the latter relation. Could someone please give me a reference or explain me how to justify it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should read $J'(v') \perp V$ and this requires differentiability of $J$. Indeed, since $J(v' + t h) \ge J(v')$ for all $t > 0$ and $h \in V$, we get
$$J'(v') h \ge 0 \qquad\forall h \in V.$$
Since $J'(v')$ is linear, this implies
$$J'(v') h = 0 \qquad\forall h \in V.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would ask you why it is true that $J(v^{\prime}+th)\ge J(v^{\prime})$ and why thw linearity of $J^{\prime}$ ensures that $J^{\prime}(v^{\prime}h=0$ for all $h\in V$. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first inequality holds since $v'$ is a minimizer. For the last step, you can insert $- h$ (instead of $h$) into $J'(v')h \ge 0$.